# Can you edit a .erb file directly from the Heroku Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, console

I am wondering if this is not possible due to version control. But, I was wondering if there was a way to directly view the code in a .html.erb file and edit it to make a small change to a typo, without having to redeploy the entire app.

I have opened the Heroku console, typed in `Dir.chdir "app/views/pages"`. That brings me to the right folder in the directory.

```
√ _testApps/[app_name] % heroku console  
irb(main):001:0> Dir.chdir "app/views/pages"
=> 0
```

I can then do `Dir.glob("*.erb")` to see a list of all of the files in that directory with that extension.

```
irb(main):002:0> Dir.glob("*.erb")
=> ["sitemap.html.erb", "about.html.erb", "home.html.erb", "guide.html.erb", 
"media_kit.html.erb", "social.html.erb", "terms_of_use.html.erb", "aids.html.erb", 
"expectations.html.erb", "faq.html.erb", "privacy_policy.html.erb", "contact_us.html.erb"]
```

Now, what I am wanting to do is something like what you can do in development to change the credentials `nano rails credentials:edit`. But, doing `nano rails home.html.erb:edit` or `nano rails home:edit` doesn't work. Here is the output with all the various ways that I tried:

```
irb(main):003:0> nano rails home.html.erb:edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from (irb):3
NameError (undefined local variable or method `home' for main:Object)

irb(main):004:0> nano rails home:edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from (irb):3
    1: from (irb):4:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NameError (undefined local variable or method `edit' for main:Object)
Did you mean?  exit

irb(main):005:0> nano home:edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from (irb):4
    1: from (irb):5:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NameError (undefined local variable or method `edit' for main:Object)
Did you mean?  exit 

irb(main):006:0> home:edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from (irb):5
    1: from (irb):6:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `home' for main:Object)

irb(main):007:0> home.html.erb:edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from (irb):6
    1: from (irb):7:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NameError (undefined local variable or method `home' for main:Object)

irb(main):008:0> edit home.html.erb
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from (irb):7
    1: from (irb):8:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NameError (undefined local variable or method `home' for main:Object)

irb(main):009:0> edit home
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from (irb):8
    1: from (irb):9:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NameError (undefined local variable or method `home' for main:Object)

irb(main):010:0> edit "home.html.erb"
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from (irb):9
    1: from (irb):10:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `edit' for main:Object)
Did you mean?  exit
```

Is this at all possible? Or is it because of version control that it is not allowed, and you have to do it locally, commit to git and then push git master to make the change? Wondering because it would be nice to make a quick edit without having to go through all those other steps. And without having to make the page dynamic and storing the information in a table to be edited in the browser.

Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First (an aside for future reference), you appear to be treating the console like it is a bash shell, but `heroku console` just spins up a Rails console. So, things like `nano rails...` don't work because they aren't valid ruby. Running `heroku run bash` will spin up a one-off dyno and give you a bash shell.

To answer your main question, pushing a git branch is the way to push your changes out. There's a couple things to understand about Heroku that help explain why:

1. When you run `heroku run bash`, Heroku spins up a separate, one-off dyno for that session with a copy of your application file structure. That's great for troubleshooting, but it's not actually connecting you in any way to the dyno running your application. So if you edit a file there, it has no effect on the running app code.
2. When you push an image to Heroku, it builds a pre-packaged image of
   your application called a slug. Whenever you restart your app it is
   reloaded from those slugs, so even if you used a hack to connect to
   your running dyno and changed a file, it would only last until the
   next time the app restarted.

Comment: Thank you for that very concise answer. ... then I am just going to have to make those small changes separately and push them up. *Thumbs up* ~ Happy Coding!